# jQuery slideUp("slow"), but always show for Desktop screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to animate `$("#somediv").slideDown("slow");` and `$("#somediv").slideUp("slow");` But when it slideUp() and you make the screen bigger, it keeps hidden.

Example:

```js
function toggle() {
    $("#somediv").slideUp("2000");
}
```

```css
/* Desktop */
@media only screen and (min-width: 1px) {
    #somediv {
        display: block;
        /* More styling */
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="toggle()">TOGGLE</a>
<div id="somediv">Div</div>
```

I've searched on the internet but couldn't find a solution.
Is this possible?

Thanks for helping!

**SOLVED** For the people with the same problem:

```
        function toggle() {
            if($("#somediv").css('display') == "none") {
                $("#somediv").slideDown("2000");
            }else {
                $("#somediv").slideUp("2000");
            }
        }
        $(window).on("resize",function(){  
            if (window.matchMedia('(min-width: 800px)').matches) {
                $("#somediv").show();
            }else {
                $("#somediv").hide();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED
For the people with the same problem:

```
        function toggle() {
            if($("#somediv").css('display') == "none") {
                $("#somediv").slideDown("2000");
            }else {
                $("#somediv").slideUp("2000");
            }
        }
        $(window).on("resize",function(){  
            if (window.matchMedia('(min-width: 800px)').matches) {
                $("#somediv").show();
            }else {
                $("#somediv").hide();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't animate `display`. You need to animate something like the height being zero or the width being zero or `transform: scale(0.0001)` or something like that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I know that things like `$("#somediv").slideDown("slow");` and `$("#somediv").slideUp("slow");` are possible, but how to make it always show for `@media only screen and (min-width: 800px)`? If I do slideUp() and make the window bigger, it keeps #somediv hidden.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
$("#somediv").slideToggle("2000");
```

instead of your toggle function and you don't need anything additional.

```js
function toggle() {
    $("#somediv").slideToggle("2000");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="toggle()">TOGGLE</a>
<div id="somediv">Div</div>
```